How do i upgrade nokogiri compatible to my rails & ruby version
I was trying to start a rails project (version 6.x), for which a nokogiri error was there:
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    The last version of nokogiri (>= 1.8.5) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 1.13.10. Try installing it with `gem install nokogiri -v 1.13.10` and then running the current command again

So i downgraded the nokogiri version and now it says:
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    There are no versions of nokogiri (~> 1.14) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 3.0, < 3.4.dev. The current ruby version is 2.6.4.104.

So i try to upgrade it again to 1.14 using
gem install nokogiri -v '1.14'

And now apparently it can't find appropriate nokogiri version to install a nokogiri version:
Fetching nokogiri-1.14.0-x86_64-linux.gem
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        There are no versions of nokogiri (= 1.14) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.7, < 3.3.dev. The current ruby version is 2.6.4.104.

I have also tried to install it using apt but that doesn't work either, I require specifically Ruby 2.6.4 & rails 6.x

If you read the message you need to go farther back in nokogiri versions that support ruby 2.6. Note that older versions of noko giri have unaddressed security issues. Likely a better use of your time to upgrade your ruby version and potentially your rails.

Did you consider using bundler to manage your project’s dependencies?

On my machine with Ruby 2.5, Rails 6 installs with nokogiri 1.12.5. Perhaps you can try that.

When starting a new Rails project, you should probably use the latest Rails version (7.2) and Ruby version (3.3) rather than try to deal with outdated and unsupported versions.

As per rubygems. Nokogiri 1.14 requires at least Ruby 2.7.

Thanks for the responses, installing railties worked for me:
apt install ruby-railties

